# get four digit year from oracle date

Tags: sql, date

I have a table A, which has a column `fromdate`.

```
select to_date(fromdate,'DD-Mon-YYYY') from A
```

returns value as `31-AUG-99`

But I need to know whether the date is `31-AUG-1999` or `31-AUG-2099`

Is there any one to help?

Comment: You are using `to_date()` the wrong way. See my explanation in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32202697/330315

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve data within a date range in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201671/retrieve-data-within-a-date-range-in-oracle)

Answer (score 3):

Use to_char function to get the date in character format.

Try this:

```
select to_char(fromdate,'DD-Mon-YYYY') from A;
```

Or if you want to want it in date then you have to change nls date settings.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-Mon-YYYY'
```

before executing your original posted query.

Comment: some comes as 2099 its clear. but now some comes as  31-Aug-0099. what does it mean by 0099?

Comment: Are u using a date datatype for your fromdate column?