# Retrieve data within a date range in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, between, date-range

I have a table tbldeptdivision as follows:

```
ID  DEPTID  DIVISIONID  FROMDATE    TODATE      REMARKS 
--- ------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------
21  21      5           31-AUG-99   01-JAN-80   NULL
```

I have the query

```
select *
  from tbldeptdivision
 where deptid = 21
   and trunc(sysdate) between to_date(fromdate,'dd-Mon-yyyy')
                          and to_date(todate,'dd-mon-yyyy');
```

It returns me no value. Can anybody say why? `'31-AUG-99'` is actually `'31-AUG-1999'` and `'01-JAN-80'` is actually `'01-JAN-2080'`. What will be the exact query?

Comment: Tag the technology you are using

Comment: what is the datatype of `FROMDATE and TODATE`. `Date or varchar`???

Comment: I am using oracle. datatype is Date

Comment: If `fromdate` is defined as a `date` then using `to_date()` to convert a `date` to a `date` is utter nonsense.

Comment: Doesn't it return nothing because it's assuming the 20th century in both columns? There's nothing between 1999 and 1980.

Comment: Are you sure the date in '80 is treated as 2080 and not 1980?  I have my doubts.  Did no-one learn from the Y2K 'crisis'?  Using two digits for the year is just stupid!

Comment: I updated the date using following query:    update tbldeptdivision set todate=to_date('01-Jan-2080','DD-Mon-YYYY') where id=21 and update tbldeptdivision set todate=to_date('01-Jan-1999','DD-Mon-YYYY') where id=21 but database showed me two digit when I retrieve the data using select * from tbldeptdivision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `todate` is a `date` your problem stems from the useless conversion of the column's value from a date to a varchar and back to a date:

`to_date()` converts a **`VARCHAR`** to a `DATE` value. If the value you pass to that function is *already* a `DATE` Oracle will first implicitely convert your date to a varchar by applying the default NLS format and will then convert *that* varchar back to a date, again applying the default NLS format.

In the first (implicit) conversion you are losing the century in your year, which consequently is then wrong when the varchar is converted back to a `date`

So in your case the following is done due to the call `to_date(fromdate,'dd-Mon-yyyy')`

- `todate` contains the (real) date value: 1980-01-30
- the implicit conversion to a varchar makes that `'01-JAN-80'`
- the conversion from the varchar to a date then assumes the year 80 should be 2080 (again based on the rules for *implicit* data type conversion).

The general rule is:

#### Do NOT use to_date() on a `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`)  column

If you need to get rid of the time part in the `DATE` column use `trunc()` instead:

```
where trunc(sysdate) between trunc(fromdate) and trunc(todate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume `FROMDATE/TODATE` datatype is `varchar2` then when you do `to_date`;

```
select to_date('01-JAN-80','dd-mon-yyyy') from dual;
OutPut: January, 01 0080 00:00:00
```

So it wont be `'01-JAN-2080'` but `'01-JAN-0080'`

Even if `FROMDATE/TODATE` datatype is `date` tusing `to_date` is not a good idea;

```
create table t(c date);
insert into t select sysdate from dual;
select c, to_date(c,'dd-mon-yyyy') from t;
```

OutPut:

```
C                           TO_DATE(C,'DD-MON-YYYY')
August, 25 2015 10:55:36    August, 25 0015 00:00:00
```

Still the year is `0015` not `2015`.

If your columns datatype is date then use `trunc to get the`date portion`don't use`to_date`.

```
select * 
from tbldeptdivision
where deptid=21
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(fromdate) 
and trunc(todate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using functions on fields in your where clause slows down production.  This is the same logic and will run faster.

```
where fromdate <= trunc(sysdate)
and todate > trunc(sysdate )
```